# Move bottom quarter of a vector to the top efficiently?

Tags: c++, vector

Given a vector with 100 elements, I want to move elements 75 to 100 to the front so that 75 is array[0], 76 is array[1] and 1 is array[25].

Thanks

Comment: do you want to overwrite the top elements, or swap them with those top 25 elements?

Comment: @Bob, it's a move, so the top elements get pushed down so what was the first element is not the 26th

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your description sounds like you need [`std::rotate`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/rotate/):

```
std::rotate(v.begin(), v.begin() + 75, v.end());
```

Comment: Much simpler choice than in my answer. :)

Comment: Thanks :-) I'd honestly like to see a competitive comparison between the two solutions, I wonder if the standard algorithm for `vector` can be beaten!

Comment: Unless your STL has specializations for the types you're using, the standard algorithms are rarely going to be the fastest choice. But unless you really need every cycle per second in the 21st century, who really cares? Write readable code, then write fast code. :)

Comment: Ah, much better. Hat tip to you, Kerrek. :)

Answer (score 3):

Pardon the additional answer, but I thought this'd best be kept separate from my original answer.

Intrigued by another poster's boasts of being able to outwit the C++ standard library, I put it to the test with this program, which implements the other poster's algorithms:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>

const std::size_t size = 25000000;
std::time_t t1, t2, t3, t4;

int main()
{
  t1 = clock();
  std::puts("Allocating...\n");

  std::vector<int> v;
  v.reserve(size);

  t2 = clock();
  std::puts("Filling...\n");

  for (std::size_t i = 0; i != size; ++i)
    v.push_back(i);

  t3 = clock();
  std::puts("Rotating...\n");

#if METHOD == 1
  // Method 1: rotate
  std::rotate(v.begin(), v.begin() + 3*size/4, v.end());
#elif METHOD == 2
  // Method 2: insert at front plus erase
  v.insert(v.begin(), &v[3*size/4], &v[size]);   // ouch, UB
  v.erase(v.begin() + size, v.end());
#elif METHOD == 3
  // Method 3: second vector
  std::vector<int> temp(&v[3*size/4], &v[size]); // ouch, UB
  v.erase(v.begin() + 3*size/4, v.end());
  v.insert(v.begin(), temp.begin(), temp.end());
#endif

  t4 = clock();

  std::puts("Done.\n");

  std::printf("Results: Allocating: %lu ms\nFilling:   %lu ms\nRotating:  %lu ms\n",
              (t2-t1)*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC, (t3-t2)*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC, (t4-t3)*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

}
```

Compiled with GCC 4.6.1 with `-std=c++0x -O3 -s -march=native -flto -DMETHOD=???`, I get the following results, after repeated runs:

[*Edit*: Added valgrind reports.]

Method 1:

```
Results: Allocating: 0 ms
Filling:   210 ms
Rotating:  140 ms

total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 100,000,000 bytes allocated
```

Method 2:

```
Results: Allocating: 0 ms
Filling:   200 ms
Rotating:  230 ms

total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 125,000,000 bytes allocated
```

Method 3:

```
Results: Allocating: 0 ms
Filling:   210 ms
Rotating:  160 ms

total heap usage: 2 allocs, 2 frees, 300,000,000 bytes allocated
```

(Valgrind reports were obtained separately from the timing. Running under valgrind, the `rotate` version is about six times faster than the other two.)

Based on this I will stand by my opinion that the standard library implementation will be a good first choice, and you will need very strong reasons for preferring a hand-rolled solution.

Comment: Nice comparison. I wonder why the third method allocates that much more storage than the second one?

Comment: @Christian Rau Maybe it's trying to allow for expansion, and it might help to reserve the correct amount of size first.

Comment: @Neil I reasoned similarly, but such an amount? The extra storage is double the size of the original data.

Answer (score 0):

```
my_vector w(v.begin() + 75, v.end());
v.resize(75);
v.insert(0, w.begin(), w.end());
```

Comment: @Andy T Sorry, I meant v.begin()

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your scenario, you can also use a larger buffer and only change the offset. This is suitable for example, for streaming data:

```
// C++
enum { kBufferSize = 1024 * 1024 }; // 1MB

char* buffer = new char[kBufferSize];

char* ptr = &buffer[0];
size_t frameSize = 100;

while(someCondition) {
    processFrame(ptr, frameSize);
    ptr += 75; // move the pointer
    // after the first loop, ptr[0] will point to buffer[75] and so on
}
```

This method has the advantage that it does not copy data and thus, is faster.